# File.makeCopy() takes 10+ seconds to run?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs

I'm trying out an idea for a Google Add-on that copies my current Google Doc and saves the new Document in another folder.

To copy my document I'm using the following code:

```
var i = 0;
docId = DriveApp.getFileById(DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId()).
        makeCopy('newDoc_' + i, DriveApp.getFoldersByName('docCopy').next()).
        getId();
```

This code accomplishes my goal of copying the file. However, the makeCopy() process seems to be taking around 10 seconds to run per document.

After running the script the Execution Transcript shows the following for the makeCopy() call:

```
File.makeCopy([newDoc_0, docCopy]) [10.996 seconds]
```

Is this normal behavior?

While this is only inconvenient for a single Document, when trying to make multiple copies the process times out at around 360 seconds - which translates to only just over 30 document copies in a single run.

Should `makeCopy()` take 10+ seconds to run? Is there a more efficient way to make a copy of a document with Google Apps Script?

Comment: Not sure if you still face difficulties with this but @Tanaike has created an explanation about the alternatives here - https://tanaikech.github.io/2018/08/23/enhanced-makecopy-using-google-apps-script/